# FFMPEG - how do I get borders on these overlaid videos

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

The included batch source below overlays 2 "feature videos" over the top of the main video.  The features fade in and out at different time intervals.

```
@set "Args="
@set "Args=%Args% [1:v]scale=480:270,fade=in:st=5:d=1:alpha=1, fade=out:st=15:d=1:alpha=1[ovr1];"
@set "Args=%Args% [2:v]scale=480:270,fade=in:st=10:d=1:alpha=1, fade=out:st=20:d=1:alpha=1[ovr2];"
@set "Args=%Args% [0:v][ovr1] overlay=W/12:H/12[tmp1];"
@set "Args=%Args% [tmp1][ovr2] overlay=W/6+100:H/6+100"

call ffmpeg -y ^
  -i "Vid0.mp4" ^
  -i "Vid1.mp4%"  ^
  -i "Vid2.mp4%"  ^
  -filter_complex "%Args%" ^
  "Output.mp4
```

This behaves as I was expecting, but I want to add borders around the videos, preferably so that the scaled size of the image is not affected, i.e. the feature video is cropped and then padded so that the displayed size of the feature is retained.

I tried this:

```
@set "Args="
@set "Args=%Args% [1:v]pad=width=iw-(iw/100):height=ih-(ih/50):x=iw/200:y=ih/100:color=violet[pad1];"
@set "Args=%Args% [pad1]scale=480:270,fade=in:st=5:d=1:alpha=1, fade=out:st=15:d=1:alpha=1[ovr1];"
@set "Args=%Args% [2:v]scale=480:270,fade=in:st=10:d=1:alpha=1, fade=out:st=20:d=1:alpha=1[ovr2];"
@set "Args=%Args% [0:v][ovr1] overlay=W/12:H/12[tmp1];"
@set "Args=%Args% [tmp1][ovr2] overlay=W/6+100:H/6+100"
```

figuring that I want to apply the border before the fade in/out so that it fades along with the contained image.  But I get this error:

`Input area -10:-12:1910:1068 not within the padded area 0:0:1900:1058 or zero-sized`

so I get that my understanding of the pad filter is incomplete.  Can somebody please help?

Actually on re-reading the question I see that my wording of the pad requirements was confusing.  What I want to do is for the padding to *encroach* on the feature video, ie if the feature video was 1920x1080, the image should be cropped to 1910x1070 and a 5 pixel border added so that the resulting image is back to 1920x1080.  This image is then presented to the scaling filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pad filter can only increase or maintain frame dimensions, not reduce them. So, you have to first crop the frame, then pad it.

So,

```
[1:v]pad=width=iw-(iw/100):height=ih-(ih/50):x=iw/200:y=ih/100:color=violet[pad1]
```

becomes

```
[1:v]crop=iw-10:ih-10,pad=w=iw+10:h=ih+10:x=-1:y=-1:color=violet[pad1]
```

The crop filter first removes 10 pixels from width and height. It will do this uniformly across all sides since that is default behaviour. The pad then adds back the 10 pixels. By setting x and y to -1* it will center the input frame in the new padded frame.

if your ffmpeg build is old, use `x=(ow-iw)/2` and `y=(oh-ih)/2`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  The fog is lifting - I'm beginning to see the filters paradigm a bit more clearly.  I do have a follow-up question - when I have a whole series of filter "clauses", with each one modifying the video in some way and writing the result to a temporary stream (and the next clause then taking that temporary stream as input) - am I slowly degrading the video quality through continual re-encoding?

Comment: No. Filters work upon uncompressed full frames, so they are only manipulating pixels or metadata. Compression occurs after all filtering is done.